# Django objects filter - AND with OR

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I need to filter objects of model class. I want to query all objects where 'date' field is in some range and one of other 2 fields are True (one or both).

Following code doesn't appear tobe working:

```
visits = Visit.objects.filter(date__range=(now, delta), Q(sms_reminder=True) | Q(email_reminder=True))
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the order of your filters:

```
visits = Visit.objects.filter(
    Q(sms_reminder=True) | Q(email_reminder=True),
    date__range=(now, delta),
)
```

From the `Q` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

> However, if a Q object is provided, it must precede the definition of any keyword arguments.

Standard python: args then kwargs. (Caught me out a few times)

Answer (score 0):

If your filter is (A OR B) AND C

You can try with this filter :

```
visits = Visit.objects.filter( (Q(sms_reminder=True)|Q(email_reminder=True)) & Q(date__range=(now, delta)))
```